# Leading TableView to MVC in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, model-view-controller

Now i get all data for cell like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TVCellTableViewCell
    
    cell.comeTypeLabel.text = "Writing off"
    cell.amountLabelCell.text =  String(RealmModel.shared.getSections()[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row].Amount)
    if RealmModel.shared.getSections()[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row].category != "" {
        cell.labelCell.text = RealmModel.shared.getSections()[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row].category
    } else {
        cell.labelCell.text = "Income"
        cell.comeTypeLabel.text = ""
    }
    return cell
}
```

It works, but i need to lead to MVC my project. So, as i understand i need to write all logic in cell class:

```
class TVCellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var labelCell: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var amountLabelCell: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var comeTypeLabel: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    labelCell.font = UIFont(name: "Gill Sans SemiBold", size: 20)
    labelCell.textColor = UIColor.black
    amountLabelCell.font = UIFont(name: "Gill Sans SemiBold", size: 20)
    amountLabelCell.textColor = UIColor.black
    comeTypeLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Gill Sans SemiBold", size: 18)
    comeTypeLabel.textColor = UIColor.gray
    
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}
```

}

But i don't know, how to do that, because "indexpathes" and other words, that i use are only allowed im tableView's functions.
Can someone show me, how to do right and lead to MVC, please

Comment: Your first snippet of code is pretty typical. You could refactor slightly to access the realm model once and store the result in a local variable, but it is otherwise fine. The other approach would be to create a function in your cell class that you call from `cellForRow`. You would pass the realm object to this function so that the cell can set its content.

Comment: You should also be careful using colours like grey and black; you will have a problem when the device switches to dark mode. You can use adaptive colours like `.label` and `tertiaryLabel`

Comment: @Paulw11, can you please tell more about a function in cell class, even better code example, because  i don't understand how to give data outside the tableView's function.

Comment: For example: labelCell.text = RealmModel.shared.getSections()

Comment: And then what? I can't use indexpath

Comment: You don't need `indexPath`. You would pass `RealmModel.shared.getSections()[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]` to the function in the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing really wrong with your first snippet, except it would probably be better to capture `RealmModel.shared.getSections()[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]` in a local variable rather than performing the indexing twice.

If you wanted to move the code to your cell, you could pass the Realm object to a function in the cell class.  You haven't provided the type of the Realm model object, so I am going to use `Item`. You would have something like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TVCellTableViewCell

    let item = RealmModel.shared.getSections()[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
    cell.configure(with: item)
     
    return cell
}

class TVCellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

//... existing code
    func configure(with item:Item) {
        if item.category.isEmpty {
            self.comeTypeLabel.text = ""
            self.labelCell.text = "Income"
        } else {
            self.comeTypeLabel.text = "Writing off"
            self.labelCell.text = item.category
        }
        self.amountLabelCell.text = String(item.amount)
     }
}
```

Note that by convention property names like `amount` should start with a lower case letter and I have made this change in the code.